# Do I need to remove the "query" part from Elastic search query when data to be find is empty?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a query that searches a given term in 2 fields.  The term is coming from an input field in the UI.If the input field is blank, the query returns no data whereas I expect that all data should be returned.

A solution is to remove the query part from the _search query, but then I need to dynamically compose my query parts.

What is the recommende way of doing this ?

My query:

```
{
 "query":{
    "filtered":{
        "query":{
          "bool":{
              "should":
                  [
                    {
                      "match":{
                          "lastName":{
                            "query": "Gevaert",
                            "fuzziness": 0.2
                          }           
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "match":{
                          "organization":{
                            "query": "Gevaert",
                            "fuzziness": 0.2
                          }           
                      }
                    }
                  ]
          }
        }
        ,
        "filter":{
            "term":{
                "category.id":"CAT102"
            }
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: may in know which programming language you are using???

Comment: Language is CSharp (.net environment).

Comment: Why don you you reconstruct query if the field is emply in application side.

Comment: That is a solution, but then I need to reconstruct a lot of queries with a lot of use cases ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also add "zero_terms_query": "all" to the match query and in that case, if no matches found, then all matches will be returned